# how to show pined location Not user Location in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, annotations, location, mapkit

I have special location in my map that is pined with latitude and longitude my problem is two things :
1- I want when I opened the app see the pined location Not user Location

2- I want user could zoom out and could see his location too (Remember that the Important thing is that I want user could find Special Location Easily when the app Runs)

here is my Code

```
@IBOutlet var map : MKMapView!
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var locationsArray = [CLLocation]()


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations[0]
    let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(35.755515 , 51.523357)
    let mylocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mylocation, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.map.showsUserLocation = true

}

let locations = [["title": "تیپو", "latitude": 35.7722206, "longitude": 51.3806899 ],]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()


    for location in locations {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.map.delegate = self

        let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.7722206, longitude: 51.3806899), addressDictionary: nil))
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.7722206, longitude: 51.3806899), addressDictionary: nil))
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
        request.transportType = .walking

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

        directions.calculate { [unowned self] response, error in
            guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

            for route in unwrappedResponse.routes {
                self.map.add(route.polyline)
                self.map.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }


    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    Manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        Manager.delegate = self
        Manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        Manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
    else{
        print("Location service disabled");
    }
}


var Manager = CLLocationManager()
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

**I Added Necessary things to Info.Plist and imported MapKit and CoreLocation and Delegate method to my class**

Comment: remove this line for first issue : self.map.showsUserLocation = true
 . and what is **Special Location**  in second issue.?

Comment: I want the app shows pined location instead of user location (and zoom to the pin location - I just can see the pin in the country map!)

Comment: did you remove suggested line ?

Comment: yes But I want to have user location too But when the app start I want go to the pined location But the user could zoom out and see his location

Comment: then first issue confused me ** Not user Location** can elaborate more.

Comment: there is an store Location that I pined in the map and user can see that _ I want when the app runs the map start zooming to the store location and the user could see the streets near the store and - user could zoom out and see his location too

Comment: I found the solution for zooming to the annotation                                            let zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
        map.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: true)
        self.map.showAnnotations(self.map.annotations, animated: true)